# Securing Java Web application

Tags: java, security, ssl, cryptography

I want to secure my web application but I'm wondering which security should I use.

For example, Is it better for me to use SSL Certification or write my own JCA (Java Cryptography Architecture Services)?

Which one give me what and what are the pros or cons of them?

If it is better to use SSL, which one is better to use? DV, OV (what are the differences for the end user)  or EV?

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Rule #1

Do not try to roll your own security procedures, protocols, mechanisms in any shape or form. Many academics dedicate a majority of their research to creating cryptographically secure algorithms for the public to use.

**Valuable** resources:

- https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/18197/why-shouldnt-we-roll-our-own
- https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=9375795
- https://www.reddit.com/r/programming/comments/3ugvo8/another_example_of_why_you_shouldnt_rollyourown/

---

On to the remainder of your; you should definitely make use of an SSL certificate primarily to secure the communication from client-to-server at a transport level (thanks to HTTPS).

That said, if you are able to obtain an Extended Validation certificate from a CA well and good and is probably a better certificate [than a Domain Validated one](https://www.digicert.com/dv-ssl-certificate.htm).

The differences for the average end-user is honestly negligible, the key here is to have HTTPS enabled. Other than that, your SSL could/should be configured at a web server level (e.g. Nginx) and essentially is language/technology agnostic.

Last point - I would highly recommend looking at [Let's Encrypt](https://letsencrypt.org/) as it allows you to programmatically setup your SSL certificates on your web server(s) including email notifications and auto-renewing certificates to avoid having them expire.